# pickerentity.key with Claims

Tags: active-directory, claims-based-auth, groups, claims, claim-provider

In a Sharepoint 2010 page, I am using a people picker to pick users or groups, SPgroups as well as Active directory groups. I am then retrieving every item that was picked as a PickerEntity.Key which I will then user later. I'm having trouble when using Claims auth. though. When I am using Claims, PickerEntity.Key will return claims encoded value, i.e. "c:0+.w|s-1-5-21-2328529170-2908158620-1515059926-513" which is the value returned when I select the Active Directory group "myDomain\Domain Users".

My question is quite simple, how can I decode the claims value "c:0+.w|s-1-5-21-2328529170-2908158620-1515059926-513" to get the ADGroup name "myDomain\Domain Users" ?

I've been searching for a couple hours now but found nothing. I thought this would be pretty straight forward... :(

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Argh! I hate when I find a solution so soon after posting my question. Finally figured out I was not looking at the right place, trying to convert the Key value. Instead I stopped using the Key property of PickerEntity and now use the DisplayText Property. Works as a charm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentionned in the Edit, I finally found a solution to my problem.